# Solve the differential equation reducible to Clairaut's form

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$y\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2+x^3\frac{dy}{dx}=x^2y$

I tried reducing to Clairaut's form but not able to do so.

Comment: It'd be nice if you showed us what you tried! Perhaps then we can get you on the right track.

Comment: I differentiated the equatuon and got a very clumsy equation. I even tried to solve for $\frac{dy}{dx}$ using the quadratic formula but was not able to make any headway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$y\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2+x^3\frac{dy}{dx}=x^2y$$
From the form of ODE, one can observe that $y(x)$ is an even function. This draw to the change of variable :

$X=x^2 \quad\to\quad \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dX}\frac{dX}{dx}=2x\frac{dy}{dX}$

$$4y\left(\frac{dy}{dX}\right)^2 +2X\frac{dy}{dX}=y$$

$4\left(\frac{ydy}{dX}\right)^2 +2X\frac{ydy}{dX}=y^2$

Obvious change of function :  $\quad Y=y^2 \quad\to\quad \left(\frac{dY}{dX}\right)^2 +X\frac{dY}{dX}=Y$

This is the Clairaut's equation. I suppose that you can continue from here.